# Get keys in JSON

Tags: json, jsonpath

I get the following JSON result from an external system:

```
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "key3": "val3"
}
```

Now I want to display all keys and all values by using JSONPath. So I am looking for something to get key1, key2 and key3 as a result. Additionally I would like to use the index of a property, e. g. `$....[2].key` to get "key3" etc.
Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Have you looked at Object.keys( ) ?

Comment: I just need the JSONPath expression (as you can test it at jsonpath.com) for that to use it in my system. Unfortunately I am not able to use javascript or any other code. I just can pass an JSONPath expression as a parameter...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found that the tilda `~` symbol is able to retrieve the keys of the values it's called upon. So for your example a query like this:

```
$.*~
```

Returns this:

```
[
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3"
]
```

Another example, if we had a JSON document like this:

```
  {
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "key3": {
      "key31":"val31",
      "key32":"val32"
  }
}
```

A query like this:

```
$.key3.*~
```

Would return this:

```
[
  "key31",
  "key32"
]
```

It's important to note that these examples work on [JSONPath.com](https://jsonpath.com) and some other simulators/online tools, but on some they don't. It might come from the fact that I found out about the tilda(~) operator in the [JSONPath plus](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath) documentation and not the official one.

Comment: Helpful answer, but for some reason doesn't work within `kubectl get .. -o jsonpath=` command. It returns list of values if i do `$.key.*`. But it returns empty list if i do `$.key.*~` or `$.key*~`

Comment: If, like me, you are using Java and Spring's `JsonPathResultMatchers` you have to use `$.keys()`. None of the above will be interpreted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the java json path use below expression:

```
 private static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
    }
    DocumentContext parsedBodyWithJsonPath = using(getConfiguration()).parse(jso);
    List<String> read = parsedBodyWithJsonPath.read("$.*");
    System.out.println("keys: "+read);
```

output :

> keys: ["$['key1']","$['key2']","$['key3']"]