# Get Json key using JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am struggling to write a JsonPath query to extract particular keys from the following sample Json.

```
{
    "initial": "somevalue",
    "somekey2": {
        "inner1": "innerval1",
        "inner2": "innerval2"
    }
}
```

For example:
1) I wish to extract the first key, which in this case is `initial`. Is this possible using JsonPath?

2) Get an inner key such as `inner1`. Something similar to `$."initial"."somekey2"` but returning an array with just the keys (`inner1` and `inner2`).

Comment: you can use Object.keys(your object) it will give an array of all key and then you can take element at [0]

Comment: @UttamUghareja that is using Javascript. I want to write the JsonPath to get the keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get keys in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471516/get-keys-in-json)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471516/get-keys-in-json) SO question covers it.

1. `$.*~` returns

```
[
  "initial",
  "somekey2"
]
```

2. `$.somekey2.*~` returns

```
[
  "inner1",
  "inner2"
]
```

3. To get all 2nd order children use `$.*.*~`. Basically for nth order, `$.(n times *).*~`

Answer (score -3):

not sure about json path, but suppose your object is a

```
a={
    "initial": "somevalue",
    "somekey2": {
        "inner1": "innerval1",
        "inner2": "innerval2"
    }
};
```

the you can get all keys by using Object.keys(a)
that will give array of keys ["initial", "somekey2"]
then you can use that key to revtrive its nested value

```
a[Object.keys(a)[1]] // returns {inner1: "innerval1", inner2: "innerval2"}
```

and you can repeat the same for all nested element

Comment: This is using JS. Take a look at what JsonPath is here: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/