# Get Names of Children in JSONPath

Tags: json, parent-child, jsonpath

I wanna get children names of this JSON via JSONPath:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "blaze": {
      "status": false
    },
    "fire": {
      "status": true
    },
    "thunder": {
      "status": false
    }
  }
}
```

and Output must be this:

```
["blaze", "fire", "thunder"]
```

but when i use `data.*`, i get incorrect and different response. I just want the correct parameter, because i'm using on several programming languages and i don't use the other referrences/functions.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `data.*` will return you the value of the objects inside the data object of your given array.
Your json -

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "blaze": {
      "status": false
    },
    "fire": {
      "status": true
    },
    "thunder": {
      "status": false
    }
  }
}
```

and the output of `$.data.*` expression -

```
[
  {
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "status": false
  }
]
```

To just access the keys of data object you have to use `~` operator.

Using the expression `$.data.*~` you will get the output as -

```
[
  "blaze",
  "fire",
  "thunder"
]
```

[Here](https://jsonpath.com/) you can test it. Credit to: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714297/5400362)

Comment: Yea, i know but in older version ~ doesn't exist